# How far back in time can Bid Manager data change?

Tags: double-click-advertising

I am just starting with DBM in a new position. We buy our DBM data from a third party provider - Datorama - and save them in our own data warehouse.

Our provider delivers a day of data from DBM each day, for other sources we have a sliding window to get data changes back in time. For some sources it might be as much as 30 days, to account for the possibility that the data can change back in time for some sources.

I'v found however that it is hard to get a straight answer whether DBM data can change back in time beyond the one day we get now. Datorama doesn't know, our in house experts in Doubleclick do not know. Right now I am trying to get the question passed along my own organisation to the people managing the doubleclick accounts.

Does anyone know if the reporting in Dourble Click Bid Manager can change back in time? Is there late arriving data that can change some of the metrics?

For some of our sources it might be some of the post click or post impression metrics that can change back in time, since a conversion might happen within a set period after the impression or the click.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

OK - the wheel have churned and we got a reply from Google:

> "Data are constantly being updated but it could take up to 48/72 hours
>   for correct data to be reflected. Furthermore we do a certification of
>   the full-month of data, 3 days after the month end, which could lead
>   to minor corrections."